# Set a property of all components of a specific type in design time

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there a way in Delphi 7 to set a property of all components on a specific type to a specific value through out the project at design time?

I have used GExperts to replace all my `TQuery`'s to `TADOQuery`'s but need to set the connection string accordingly.

I have tried using GExperts "Set Component Properties" but that doesnt seem to work on the connection property.

I thought of doing a search and replace in the .dfm files but the connection property is not stored in the .dfm file until it is manually set.

Comment: Maybe you can search all DFM's and replace "= TADOQuery" with "= TADOQuery connection=xyz"...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be smarter to link all of your queries to a `TADOConnection` and specify your connection string on that component alone. The connection string is one thing that's likely going to change a few times during development, not to mention it's likely to change from client-to-client. Having it on every single `TADOQuery` is equivalent to hard-coding it. That can't be a good idea.

Secondly, give it a good thought, use a grep tool to check the actual number of `TADOQuery` components you've got. It might very well be possible to do this by hand, without any tool of any kind: can't speak for others, but I'm sure I'd rather change 100 queries by hand then bother with a tool. Even if you use a tool, you'll still need to check all of the DFM's to make sure they're still in working order. That requires you to open them all in the IDE.

Finally, since the answer to this question would not be complete without an automatic way of doing this, here's a simple way.

Here's a short procedure that takes the name of DFM file, the name of a component class and the value you want in the DFM. It'll look for the value and make sure the property has the given name. If the property doesn't exist, it adds the property. You'd use it like this:

```
FixComponentPropertyInDFM('Unit16.dfm', 'TPanel', 'Caption', '''Changed Caption''');
```

**The Code**, not using Regular Expressions to make sure it compiles in Delphi 7. Half the code deals identifying patterns in the DFM file, so using regular expressions would make the code 1/4 in size.

```
procedure FixComponentPropertyInDFM(const FileName:string; const ClassName, PropertyName, RequiredValue: string);
var L: TStringList;
    i,j, iEnd, iLine: Integer;
    ExtraObjectCount: Integer;
    cLine, trimedLine, TestLine: string;
    lcSufixString: string;
    lcSufixLen: Integer;
    lcPropertyPrefix: string;
    lcPropertyPrefixLen: Integer;
    DelphiId: AnsiString;
    ValidId: Boolean;
    CorrectLineValue: string;

    ChangedTheDFM: BOolean;
begin
  lcSufixString := LowerCase(': ' + ClassName);
  lcSufixLen := Length(lcSufixString);

  lcPropertyPrefix := LowerCase(PropertyName + ' =');
  lcPropertyPrefixLen := Length(lcPropertyPrefix);

  CorrectLineValue := PropertyName + ' = ' + RequiredValue;

  ChangedTheDFM := False;

  L := TStringList.Create;
  try
    L.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    i := 0;
    while i < L.Count do
    begin
      cLine := L[i];
      // Is the current line of the form [object Name: ClassName] ?
      if (Length(cLine) > lcSufixLen) and (LowerCase(System.Copy(cLine, Length(cLine)-lcSufixLen+1, lcSufixLen)) = lcSufixString) then
      begin
        // This line is most likely the start of an object definition, of the type I want.
        // Check this further: does it start with "object"?
        trimedLine := Trim(cLine);
        if LowerCase(System.Copy(trimedLine, 1, 7)) = 'object ' then
        begin
          // Further checks. Doesn't hurt to be extra-safe.
          System.Delete(trimedLine, 1, 7);
          System.Delete(trimedLine, Length(trimedLine) - lcSufixLen+1, System.MaxInt);
          trimedLine := Trim(trimedLine);
          // What's left should be a valid Identifier. Also check that!
          DelphiId := AnsiString(trimedLine); // I'm writing this on Delphi2010, but I want the code to compile on Delphi 7; And I want to use the "char-in-set"
          if (Length(DelphiId) > 0) and (DelphiId[1] in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_']) then
          begin
            ValidId := True;
            for j:=2 to Length(DelphiId) do
              if not (DelphiId[j] in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_', '0'..'9']) then
                ValidId := False;
            if ValidId then
            begin
              // This line passed all tests. I know *for sure* an object definition of the required class starts here.
              iLine := -1; // Line where the property definition was found in the DFM
              iEnd := -1; // Line where the "end" that finishes the definition was found
              ExtraObjectCount := 0; // Counts the depth for the extra objects we might find.
              j := i+1;
              while (iEnd = -1) and (j < L.Count) do
              begin
                TestLine := LowerCase(Trim(L[j]));
                if System.Copy(TestLine, 1, 7) = 'object ' then Inc(ExtraObjectCount)
                else if System.Copy(TestLine, 1, 10) = 'inherited ' then Inc(ExtraObjectCount)
                else if TestLine = 'end' then
                  begin
                    // I'm seeing the end of an object. Don't know if it's *our* object
                    // or some other object.
                    Dec(ExtraObjectCount);
                    if ExtraObjectCount = -1 then iEnd := j; // Our object.
                  end
                else if ExtraObjectCount = 0 then
                  begin
                    // We know we're within our object, not some embeded object.
                    if System.Copy(TestLine, 1, lcPropertyPrefixLen) = lcPropertyPrefix then
                      iLine := j;
                  end;
                // Next line
                Inc(j);
              end;
              // Alter the DFM!
              if iLine = -1 then
                begin
                  // Did not find the line.
                  if iEnd = -1 then raise Exception.Create('BUG: Did not find "end"');
                  L.Insert(iEnd, CorrectLineValue);
                  ChangedTheDFM := True;
                end
              else
                begin
                  // Found the value.
                  if Trim(L[iLine]) <> CorrectLineValue then
                  begin
                    L[iLine] := CorrectLineValue;
                    ChangedTheDFM := True;
                  end;
                end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;

      // Next line
      Inc(i);
    end;

    if ChangedTheDFM then
    begin
      // Make a backup of the original DFM.
      if FileExists(FileName + '.backup') then
        raise Exception.Create(FileName + '.backup already exists.');
      if not CopyFile(PChar(FileName), PChar(string(FileName + '.backup')), True) then
        raise Exception.Create('Can''t create BACKUP file.');
      L.SaveToFile(FileName);
    end;

  finally L.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will give this a try. Sorry, my question was misleading, it is the Connection property, not the ConnectionString of each TADOQuery that I want to set.